# PostCSS and Tailwind Config Error When Hosting on a Server

Tags: css, tailwind-css, vite, postcss

I'm currently creating a small app with Vite, using tailwind and postcss for styling. Everything works fine locally, and I'm able to run `npm run build`, and everything builds fine with vite. However, when I upload it to "Render" for server hosting, I get this error during the build stage:

`Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /opt/render/project/src): [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'`

From doing research, I've seen people say that it's because I don't have a compatible version of vite, postcss, and tailwind. However, why would it work locally with my current versions and not on a server? Thanks!

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tip-calculator-server",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "convert-time": "^0.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.3",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.16",
    "vite-express": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.26",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```